# How to write an AGI Script

Tags: asterisk, telephony, agi

I am fairly new to the Asterisk Gateway Interface. Couple of questions.

1. What language would be suggested to start out with.

My end goal is to have a script that automatically page when a call is parked. In esscence, the operator would park the call and then presented with a selection (eg. 1 for management, 2 for IT, 3 for marketing, etc...) and once the entry is set an automated page would go out and say something "Management pick up on 71. Management 71."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of my knowledge, php is easy and simple.

i think, the following links help you ...

PHP

http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/

sample code :

http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/phpagi22/api-docs/

Asterisk.NET ( C# )

http://sourceforge.net/projects/asterisk-dotnet/

Answer (score 1):

to start, its best to use the favourite scripting language of your taste.
Personally i prefer PHP for small scripts, because i feel at home.
Also, there is a PHP wrapper for most AGI commands called [phpagi](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/).

Of course there is the same sort of wrapper library for Perl, Python ...

just use the language you like most.